# Codeigniter get_instance() in a view

Tags: codeigniter, security

In my app, i use `get_instance()` in my view, below is my complete code

`<h3 class="title">
    <?php echo get_instance()->router->fetch_method();?>
</h3>`

what it is dangerous?

Comment: Are you know the purpose of using `get_instance` ?? and what you need to do??

Comment: I think get instance is more for the library and helper side of things. Are you trying to load controller function in view? You might be best to look at HMVC for codeigniter 3 https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

Comment: Dangerous? Maybe. Hard to know without understanding what router and fetch_method() are doing. It looks like a failure to follow a good "Separation of Concerns" principles.

Comment: ok, thank for your opinion. all.